# Christmas wishes to multiple persons

Tags: word-choice, christmas

I'm sending an email to Alice (person A) and I cc Bob (person B). The email begins with

> Dear Alice,
>
> [Text]
>
> Wishing you Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!
>
> Regards
>
> Jim

While I am addressing Alice, I want to make it clear that my wishes are for both Alice and Bob. The first thing that came to my mind is to replace the line "Wishing you Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!" and to say

> Wishing you Alice and Bob Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!

instead.
Is it needed? And if yes, is this the aforementioned way the right way to say that?

Comment: ....Dear Yu'le.

Comment: "Dear Yu'le." What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: Why are you cc'ing Bob, which implies that you merely want him to be aware that you have emailed Alice rather than addressing him directly?

Comment: A bit of a stretch Edwin, but funny regardless.

Comment: Switch to the trombone.

Comment: Bah, humbug . . .

Comment: "Wishing you and yours a Merry Christmas and a Happy Star Wars Day".

Comment: But why are you dissing Ted and Carol by not including them too?

Answer (score 2):

> **Wishing you both a Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!**

I believe that will serve your purpose (and if you were addressing more than two people, you could replace "both" with "all").

As to the correctness of "Wishing you Alice and Bob Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year," I think it suffers a comma deficiency and should be: "Wishing you, Alice and Bob, Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year." I still find that clunky, but it's correct.

Comment: You have to reposition, surely: _Alice and Bob_ ... Wishing you ...

Comment: Surely? I admit it's clunky, but it's not "incorrect."